# about "fracture" issue of non-regularized autoencoders

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, autoencoders

In Page 12 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05644.pdf, they mentioned that a drawback of non-regularized autoencoders is:

"but it is widely known that non-regularized autoencoders “fracture” the manifold into many different domains which result in very different codes for similar images [Hinton]"

They did not provide reference in the paper and I searched it in Google but did not find related information.  Could anyone provide any links or papers on this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue of manifold fracturing is mentioned in this set of lecture notes by Hinton:

```
University of Toronto Computer Science 
CSC 2535: 2013 
Lecture 11 
Non-linear dimensionality reduction 
Geoffrey Hinton
```

See slides 73-79

https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/csc2535/notes/lec11new.pdf

Synopsis of slides 73-79: Unlike PCA, nonlinear autoencoders can potentially fracture a manifold into many different domains, leading to very different codes in the embedding layer for nearby data points in the original space.

Hinton offers Stochastic Neighbor Embedding as a regularizer that would make it costly to fracture the manifold:  "Its like putting springs between the codes to prevent the codes for similar datapoints from being too far apart."

Comment: Your answer should contain more than just a link.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Didn't realize this applies when a person only asks for references rather than an explanation.

Comment: One rationale is that links can die but CV wants to preserve the questions and answers.

Comment: Take my suggestion to elaborate because apparently the OP is very happy with your answer. Simply edit the answer to give a complete citation for the reference.

Comment: Michael, may I ask for one more review?  I appreciate your guidance on my first attempt at an answer here.

Comment: I like your answer.  I am not really up on this subject,